# Transforming an array into an object?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to transform the following array of objects into an object that contains the label property as the key to multiple arrays of objects containing that same key as the property.

Here's a JSBin of a function that maps the array but I'm not sure about the ES6 logic I would use to get the output I want.

https://jsbin.com/foyijisaku/1/edit?js,console

**original array**

```
var originalArray =

    [
      {
        'id': 6,
        'label': 'hello'
      },
      {
        'id': 5,
        'label': 'hello'
      },
      {
        'id': 4,
        'label': 'bye'
      },
      {
        'id': 3,
        'label': 'bye'
      },
      {
        'id': 2,
        'label': 'bye'
      },
      {
        'id': 1,
        'label': 'bye'
      }
    ]
```

**new object**

```
var newObject =

    {
        'hello': [
            {
                'id': 6,
              'label': 'hello'
            },
            {
                'id': 5,
              'label': 'hello'
            },
        ],
        'bye': [
            {
                'id': 4,
              'label': 'bye'
            },
            {
                'id': 3,
              'label': 'bye'
            },
            {
                'id': 2,
              'label': 'bye'
            },
            {
                'id': 1,
              'label': 'bye'
            },
        ]
    }
```

Comment: ES6/ES2015 has nothing to do with it. What have you tried?

Comment: You'll need to manually write your own reducer. Check out https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce

Comment: Reducer is what I was looking for thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var originalArray =

    [
      {
        'id': 6,
        'label': 'hello'
      },
      {
        'id': 5,
        'label': 'hello'
      },
      {
        'id': 4,
        'label': 'bye'
      },
      {
        'id': 3,
        'label': 'bye'
      },
      {
        'id': 2,
        'label': 'bye'
      },
      {
        'id': 1,
        'label': 'bye'
      }
    ]

var newObject = originalArray.reduce(function(accumulator, current) {
  accumulator[current.label] = accumulator[current.label] || [];
  accumulator[current.label].push({
    id: current.id,
    label: current.label
  });
  return accumulator;
}, {})
```

In ES6, with spread operator:

```
var newObject = originalArray.reduce((accumulator, current) => {
  accumulator[current.label] = accumulator[current.label] || [];
  accumulator[current.label].push({...current});
  return accumulator;
}, {})
```

The reason why current is not directly pushed is to avoid keeping reference.

Comment: Thanks a lot, going to spend some time going through this code.

Answer (score 0):

You need to iterate over the entire array. You can do this with a `for...in` loop.

```
var newObject;
for(var o in originalArray){
    if(o.label == 'hello'){
        var len = object['hello'].length;
        object['hello'][len] = o;
    }else{
        var len = object['bye'].length;
        object['bye'][len] = o;
    }
}
```

Comment: [Don't use `for...in` for arrays.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9329446/for-each-over-an-array-in-javascript) Use a normal `for` loop or [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)